# What's the purpose of "ExecutionPolicy" settings in PowerShell if the "-bypass" switch circumvents it?

Tags: powershell

PowerShell's "ExecutionPolicy" allows for restricting all scripts from running, only allowing signed scripts, etc - [see this article for reference](http://ss64.com/ps/set-executionpolicy.html).

However, if I simply do:

```
PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file MyScript.ps1
```

... I have effectively circumvented the configured Execution Policy anyway, and the script is successfully run (even with a completely 'Restricted' default policy configured).

**What's the point in having different levels of policies available, if all I have to do is send a switch to bypass it, and it'll succeed?**  Am I missing somewhere that 'Bypass' won't work under specific circumstances?  So far, I've not found an execution policy that wouldn't let it slip right on by anyway.

*(Sincerest apologies if this were better suited for StackOverflow, but I came here first, since it deals with security policies.  I've searched a while to find an answer on this, but I can't seem to find a definitive explanation.)*

Comment: This is exactly where this post belongs BTW, IMO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/) (em mine):

> ## What is the PowerShell Execution Policy?
>
> The PowerShell execution policy is the setting that determines which
>   type of PowerShell scripts (if any) can be run on the system. By
>   default it is set to "Restricted", which basically means none.
>   However, **it's important to understand that the setting was never meant**
>   **to be a security control**. Instead, it was intended to prevent
>   administrators from shooting themselves in the foot

Comment: And it's easily bypassed with a one-liner `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\circumvent\industry\standard.ps1" 2>&1>$null` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529433/powershell-exe-executionpolicy-bypass-header-in-script

Comment: Why "Crutches" are actually a BAD thing for sysadmins! Linux Rules!! --> https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sysadmins-dont-sudo